# Close running application on uninstalling

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I use ClikOnce for installation my application. But, when application is running and you try to delete it, ClickOnce says that application was deleted, but program is still running.

I know it will be deleted after reboot. But, my program can be autostarted. Therefore, it won't be deleted.

So, how can I force ClickOnce to close the application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
foreach (Process prog in Process.GetProcessesByName("MSACCESS")) {
    if (prog.ProcessName == "MSACCESS") {
        prog.Kill();
    }
}
```

You need to change "MSACCESS" with your own application proccess name.

Comment: Could you give me some details? Where I have to call this code?

Comment: you can use this on anywhere..let say when you click button or whatever..then just use this code

Comment: I can't use it anywhere. Read question, please.  There is no entry point for uninstalling clickonce app.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. I though you just want to Close running Application.